# Проверить наличие/отстутствие пропусков

Tags: c#, linq

Есть некоторый массив строк, заранее упорядоченных по алфавиту.

```
public string[] GetSampleSource()
{
    return new string[] {
        "9U","9V","9W","9X","9Y","9Z","A0","A1","A2","A3","A4",
        "A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF",
        "AG","AH","AI","AJ","AK","AL","AM","AN","AO","AP","AQ",
        "AR","AS","AT","AU","AV","AW","AX","AY","AZ","B0","B1",
        "B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7"
    };
}
```

Нужно проверить, нет ли в них каких-то пропусков: например, что после 6S идёт не 6T, а сразу 6W.

Можно ли такое провернуть в linq?

Comment: Сгенерировать коллекцию заведомо без пропусков и вычесть из нее эту?

Comment: Угу, я на шаге вычесть как раз и запнулся: `Enumerable.Range(0, this.GetSampleSource().Length)`. Хотел сначала в hex привести, но там не только 0...F - но весь алфавит. Так что до вычитания не дошёл.

Comment: Ну да, потребуется функция для перевода в 36-ричную СС

Comment: Оу, даже что-то готовое гуглится и на тему системы с основанием 36. Может и сам дам успею написать ответ вечером, пока на работе аврал. И даже Nuget есть готовый: https://github.com/tallesl/net-36

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если по условию задачи массив уже отсортирован, то можно просто из последнего элемента вычесть первый и сравнить с длинной массива:

```
var source = this.GetSampleSource();

if(source.Length == 0 || Base36.Decode(source[source.Length - 1]) - Base36.Decode(source[0]) == source.Length - 1) {
    // нет пропусков
} else {
    // есть пропуски
}
```

Comment: Галка за более простой алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, дошли руки. Как-то так:

```
var source = this.GetSampleSource();

var t1 = Enumerable.Range((int)Base36.Decode(source.First()), this.GetSampleSource().Length);
var t2 = source.Select(x => (int)Base36.Decode(x));

var t = t1.Zip(t2, (x,y) => x - y);
//t.Dump();

if(t.All(x => x == 0))
    "нет пропусков".Dump();
else
    "есть пропуски".Dump();
```

PS Использовался готовый [nuget-пакет для работы системой счисления по основанию 36](https://github.com/tallesl/net-36).

Comment: Оу. Целая либа для работы с одной единственной системой счисления... Как-то это неправильно хД

Comment: Воу, зачем `Zip`, есть же специально для вычитания множеств `Except`, ну и для перевода в Base36 можно написать простую функцию из трех строк

Comment: Я бы так написал: https://ideone.com/ndux9y Постить отдельно не буду, т. к. идея всё та же

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, YAGNI

Comment: @АндрейNOP: для **АК**-то все хорошо. Он нашёл нужный себе функционал и может жить спокойно. Я говорю конкретно о библиотеке и конкретно с той точки зрения, что алгоритм перевода числа в систему счисления с основанием N - всегда один и тот же. Вне зависимости от самого N. Так что брать и ориентироваться на какое-то конкретное N...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Писалось всё вчера на бегу и в спешке, поэтому времени особо подумать не было. Поэтому за замечания спасибо, сам не заметил.